GEE Landsat / Sentinel images not displaying
I am trying to display all Landsat 8 and Sentinel 2 images for a location during a specified time period. My code returns 6 images for the former and 68 for the latter. I have a Layer dropdown where I can select which image to display. But no matter what the display settings they don't actually show
// Define the date range
var startDate = '2023-12-01';
var endDate = '2024-02-28';

// Load the Landsat 8 collection
var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(roi);
  });

// Load the Sentinel-2 collection
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(roi);
  });

// Print the number of images in each collection
print('Number of Landsat 8 images:', landsat8.size());
print('Number of Sentinel-2 images:', sentinel2.size());

// Function to add images to the map with date in layer name
function addImagesToMap(imageCollection, name, visParams) {
  var imageList = imageCollection.toList(imageCollection.size());
  var count = imageCollection.size().getInfo();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(i));
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo();
    var imageName = name + ' ' + date;
    Map.addLayer(image, visParams, imageName);
  }
}

// Visualization parameters
var landsatVisParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.3,
  gamma: 1.4
};

var sentinelVisParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4
};

// Add Landsat 8 images to the map
addImagesToMap(landsat8, 'Landsat 8', landsatVisParams);

// Add Sentinel-2 images to the map
addImagesToMap(sentinel2, 'Sentinel-2', sentinelVisParams);

// Center the map on the ROI
Map.centerObject(roi, 10);



Your ROI is a point and you're clipping to the ROI on line 8.  So every image is 1 pixel in size.

Ah! Yes, thank you! Fixed.
